# Change Everything css styles when i link the bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> <!--Supporting All devices width-->
    <meta name="description" content="Lowa State University Library">
    <meta name="keywords" content="For a Web Design Assignment">
    <meta name="author" content="Tharuka Dananjaya">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap.css">-->


</head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <div id="head_top">
                    <h1>LOWA STATE UNIVERSITY | <span class="highlight"> LIBRARY</span></a></h1>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <li class="current"><a href="librarian_home.php">Home</a></li>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="button_book">Books</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                          <a href="#">Link 4</a>
                          <a href="#">Link 5</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <!--<a href="loginindex.php">Login</a>
                        <a href="registerindex.php">Register</a>-->
                        <a href="student_info.php" class="ma">Student Info</a>


                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="search_bar">
                <div class="container">
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
                        <button type="search" class="button_1">search</button>
```

`I have external CSS file and Bootstrap. i already link my CSS style in my page and it's work perfect. so I'm try create a table using bootstrap. but after linking bootstrap files in page change every styles. ex. header fonts, everything. So how do i link both Styles and i need both styles.[After Linking Bootstrap file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxY6r.png)

Comment: Please share your code .

Comment: Hi, shareyour code. We don't know what change in your project, and your question is to generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're importing your custom styles BEFORE Bootstrap; as soon as you import bootstrap it will override the classes you may have created in your CSS file.

Try importing bootstrap before your own CSS and see if that makes a difference.

Without any code it's all I can help you at this moment.

### Edit

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap.css">-->
```

As I can see you were indeed importing bootstrap after your own CSS rules. That way Bootstrap is going to override your classes in your CSS files. To get around this flip the order of these two statements so your CSS has prevalence over what Bootstrap states.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
```

Also, if you're not providing any `font-family` attributes in your CSS it's going to use Bootstrap's default. Don't forget to **override all necessary classes AND elements (body, p, div...)**.

Further info on how to apply theming in your own Bootstrap instance can be found [here, in the official Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/).

Extra tip while debugging: Check in the developer environment you're not getting any `404` in the network requests regarding your links to your own stylesheets since it feels like your styles are not working but actually they are never reaching the browser

Answer (score 2):

Please first add bootstrap style and then your style.css.
Like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
```

in your index.html file in the head section.

The priority of css works from bottom to top.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
```

Compiler tends to read code from line 1. If you put bootstrap.css after the style.css. Definitely bootstrap.css will overwrite style.css.

Answer (score 0):

hi Tharuka Dananjaya,
  the problem was totally made from bootstrap external css only.
  how to solve?
  1. first to check which section is breaking and inspect the element, you can see
     the browser take the boostrap css not your style.
     so what to do , make that particular css as **!important**
     *eg: color:red!important;*

2. make your style high priority!
    copy your whole code from style.css, and paste in your html page
    as internal css styling way, which means put in b/w head and body.