# Is it possible to make a div visible inside a wrapper display: none div without changing the wrapper div

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a wrapper `div` with the following classes `d-none d-lg-block`. This is to ensure it only visible in large screens.

Within this wrapper `div` I have another `div` which I need to make visible when the user clicks on a button. I have tried overriding display, z-index, position properties, but it seems like the wrapper `d-none` is not overridable. I need a solution without changing the wrapper `div` (removing the `d-none` class) as it contains other items which must stay invisible to the user.

Example

```js
$("#btn").on('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("text-to-display").classList.toggle("display-me");
});
```

```css
.display-me {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col d-none">
      <h2 id="text-to-display">Should be visible</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" id="btn">
      <button>Click me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codeply Examnple](https://www.codeply.com/p/HvCMhAJ31v)

Answer (score 0):

You hided the entire div using `d-none`, so the elements present inside `div` always pretend to be hidden because the parent itself is not visible.
So Just change your JavaScript code, change toggling `.display-me` on `<h2>` to `<div>`.

Since you are using bootstrap, `d-none` also contains `display: none !important`. So better mention your class in `<style>` or else add your `<link href='style.css'>` after bootstrap's link. [Check This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56438514/change-everything-css-styles-when-i-link-the-bootstrap)

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
    $(".col.d-none").toggleClass("display-me");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
  .display-me {
      position: absolute;
      top: 30px;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 9999;
      display: block !important;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col d-none">
            <h2 id="text-to-display">Should be visible</h2>        
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" id="btn">
            <button>Click me</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And In your JS code, Half the part is jQuery and half the part is vanilla JS and it won't work.

**Vanilla JS code**

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(){
    document.querySelector(".col.d-none").classList.toggle("d-block");
}
```

**Additional :** Since you are using bootstrap simply you can use `d-block` instead of `display-me` as shown above. `.display-me` contains all unnecessary properties to display except `display` property.
If you don't want to apply toggle on `.col.d-none` then move `id` from `h2` to `div` and apply `onclick` to `id`.